# Push child property to parent object using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have nested object like following:

```js
{
Campaign_Type: 1
Campaign_TypeFull: {text: "Test my campaign", value: 1}
End_Date: "07/26/2019"
Live_Date: "07/15/2019"
Name: "Death of An Art Collector - Book Signings"
Status: "ACTIVE"
}
```

Output I require is to convert `Campaign_TypeFull` child object into parent object property as my react material table only accepts flat array.

```js
{
Campaign_Type: 1
text: "Test my campaign",
value: 1,
End_Date: "07/26/2019"
Live_Date: "07/15/2019"
Name: "Death of An Art Collector - Book Signings"
Status: "ACTIVE"
}
```

I tried using `flatmap` or map but couldn't get it working (I am using `lodash`).

```
let griddata = flatMap(tabledata,({ _id,Name, Status,Live_Date, End_Date, Campaign_TypeFull }) => map(Campaign_TypeFull, Campaign_TypeFull => ({...Campaign_TypeFull, _id,Name, Status,Live_Date, End_Date })))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with some object destructuring fairly easily

```js
const data = { Campaign_Type: 1,Campaign_TypeFull: { text: "Test my campaign",value: 1},End_Date:"07/26/2019",Live_Date: "07/15/2019",Name: "Death of An Art Collector - Book Signings",Status: "ACTIVE"}


const flattenCampaign = ({Campaign_TypeFull, ...rest}) => {
    return Object.assign({},  Campaign_TypeFull, rest);
};

console.log(flattenCampaign(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use lodash merge, and merge the objects together & then get rid of the merged property.

```js
const obj = {
  Campaign_Type: 1,
  Campaign_TypeFull: {
    text: "Test my campaign",
    value: 1
  },
  End_Date: "07/26/2019",
  Live_Date: "07/15/2019",
  Name: "Death of An Art Collector - Book Signings",
  Status: "ACTIVE",
}

const flatobj = _.merge(obj, obj.Campaign_TypeFull);
delete flatobj.Campaign_TypeFull;
console.log(flatobj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash you can create a function with `_.flow()`, that creates an object without the property (using `_.omit()`), and gets the property values, and then merges them together:

```js
const { flow, over, partialRight: pr, spread, merge, get, omit } = _

const flattenProperty = key => flow(
  over([pr(omit, key), pr(get, key)]), // get an array of [obj without key, key values]
  spread(merge) // merge together
)

const obj = {"Campaign_Type":1,"Campaign_TypeFull":{"text":"Test my campaign","value":1},"End_Date":"07/26/2019","Live_Date":"07/15/2019","Name":"Death of An Art Collector - Book Signings","Status":"ACTIVE"}

const result = flattenProperty('Campaign_TypeFull')(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you've go an object with multiple nested properties, you wish to flatten in a single go, you can use `_.transform()` to create a flatten object function:

```js
const flattenObj = obj => _.transform(obj, (r, v, k) => {
  if(_.isObject(v)) _.assign(r, flattenObj(v))
  else r[k] = v
})

const obj = {"Campaign_Type":1,"Campaign_TypeFull":{"text":"Test my campaign","value":1},"End_Date":"07/26/2019","Live_Date":"07/15/2019","Name":"Death of An Art Collector - Book Signings","Status":"ACTIVE"}

const result = flattenObj(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```